# Mockito verify with timeout failes unpredictably on concurrent execution

Tags: java, junit, concurrency, mocking, executorservice

I just written a Mockito code to test  `verify(mock, timeout())` feature when concurrently invoked a method on a mock object.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class MockitoTest {
    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Stream.generate(() -> new Object[]{}).limit(100).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Test
    public void testVerifyTimeout() throws Exception {
        List listMock = mock(List.class);
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        Stream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1).limit(10).map(i -> new AddToListTask(listMock, i)).forEach(executorService::submit);
        verify(listMock, timeout(1000)).add(2);
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

    private static class AddToListTask implements Callable<Void> {
        private final List<Integer> list;
        private final int value;

        public AddToListTask(List<Integer> list, int value) {
            this.list = list;
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            list.add(value);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This test fails randomly 10-20 times out of 100 runs. This is a very basic case where we run a mock method concurrently, and the result is not always verified correctly.
Each test runs about 25ms-50ms, but even if it fails, it does not wait for 1 sec.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mockito 1.9.0 this was a bug, but already has been fixed, so from version 1.9.5 and onward (including 1.10.x, 2.x) works well.